# Compounding Interest

Tags: loans, banking, interest, deposits, maturity

How to calculate compounding interest and maturity value of recurring deposit.
e.g. Mr A deposit $ 1000 per month in bank @ 5% p.a. for 5 years. Interest compound quarterly. How t0 calculate maturity value.
Plzz guide..

Answer (score 1):

The annual nominal interest is 5% compounded quarterly: `i = 0.05`

so the quarterly interest `q = i/4 = 0.0125`

The annual [effective interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) `a = (1 + q)^4 - 1 = 0.0509453`

Monthly interest `r = (1 + a)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.00414943`

or in one step `r = (1 + i/4)^(4/12) - 1 = 0.00414943`

The maturity value `s` is the sum of the deposits with compounded interest

[image]

(*formula derived* [*here*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Derivation))

So with `d = 1000` and `n = 60` months

```
s = (d (1 + r) ((1 + r)^n - 1))/r = 68252.23
```

The total interest is `s - n d = 8252.23`

***Check***

Confirming with the online calculator posted by C8H10N4O2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to look up the future value of a growing ordinary annuity, taking care to compound quarterly. See [this online calculator](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/future-value-annuity-calculator.php).